# Table Variable As a parameter In My sql Stored Procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, mysql

Can i pass table variable as a PARAMETER To a Stored Procedure in MySql

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a table into the stored procedure as parameter - then answer is no. Only scalar values can be passed.

The table can be accessed by its name directly; if you want to use that table name to construct and run new query in procedure, then have a look at [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 0):

By looking at prepared statements, I ended up creating this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SELECT_FROM`(IN `TBName` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN

  SET @SQLString = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `", TBName, "` ;");

  PREPARE qry FROM @SQLString;
  EXECUTE qry;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

yes

```
    TableA:
    MyId       MyNumber
    1          5
    2          6
    3          9


Select myNumber, MyStoredProcedure(MyNumber) from TableA where MyNumber > 5
```

Comment: This question is about mysql.  This does not work in mysql.