# How to insert variable parameter to SQL stored procedure in Flask app

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, flask, pyodbc

I am looking for some advice for my Flask app. I want for a user to be able to click on a name of a product and when they click, it brings user to a new page with table of historical orders for that specific item. I have looked at these two questions (and more) but they don't seem to have the answer I'm looking for. 
[Table Variable As a parameter In My sql Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118247/table-variable-as-a-parameter-in-my-sql-stored-procedures)
[how to pass output parameter to ms-sql stored procedure using knex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813209/how-to-pass-output-parameter-to-ms-sql-stored-procedure-using-knex).

In my app.py file, I have the following stored procedure -

```
order_history = '''exec Web_ProductHistory ?'''
```

And here is the associated route and function for it -

```
@app.route('/prev-orders/')
def previous_orders():
   ItemID = request.form.get('ItemID')
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute(order_history, (ItemID))
   data = cursor.fetchall()
   return render_template('previous-orders.html', data=data)
```

I have a table filled with stock items working and here is the table -

```
{% for value in data %}
       <tr>
          <td class="hidden"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><span style="margin-left: 40px">{{ value[1] }}</span></td>
          <td><a name="{{ value[0] }}" class="black-text" href="{{url_for('previous_orders')}}" target="_blank">{{ value[3] }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ value[12] }}</td>
          <td>{{ value[23] }}</td>
          <td class="over-25">{{ value[18] }}</td>
          <td>{{ value[6] }}</td>
          <td>{{ value[7] }}</td>
          <td><a name="{{ value[0] }}" class="black-text" href="{{url_for('live_so')}}" target="_blank">{{ value[14] }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ value[16] }}</td>
          <td>{{ value[15] }}</td>
          <td>{{ value[22] }}</td>
          <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

value[0] is the ItemID integer.

So far, I have tried to change the route to *@app.route('/prev-orders/')* or *@app.route('/prev-orders/ItemID')* but that doesn't do it. I then tried to change the second line to 
def previous_orders(ItemID) but that doesn't get it working either.

Have you any tips for me to try to get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.form.get('ItemID')
```

This expects the `ItemID` to be posted.  If you want to pass it within the URL, then do something like:

```
@app.route('/prev-orders/<integer:ItemID>')
def previous_orders(ItemID):
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   # ... rest of code
```

Then generate the link in your HTML with:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('previous_orders', ItemID = value[0]) }}">{{ value[3] }}</a>
```

---

Also, as a side note, I think the following line should be:

```
cursor.execute(order_history, (ItemID,))
```

(note the extra comma which makes that second argument a valid tuple, which I think is what the `execute` method expects)